# Should a @Singleton bean return an internal List<> member?

Tags: java, java-ee-6

This is possibly a really easy question, but it's something that's not entirely clear to me.

I have a bean as follows:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@Lock(READ)
public class SomeDataBean {
  List<Foo> foos;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    // Build foos;
  }

  public List<Foo> getFoos() {
    return foos;
  }

  @Lock(WRITE)
  public void modifyFoos() {
    // This could be potentially called too
  }
}
```

Subsequently, this bean is injected (using CDI - environment is Wildfly 8.2), into various other beans (Request/Session/View etc.) Now they all access this list of `Foo`s. My question is, is it safe to return the list as is, when potentially `modifyFoos()` could be invoked by another bean. Or is this something that will never happen and is guaranteed by the container?

I've read some of the docs on the container managed transactions etc, but it's not entirely clear how it works in situations such as this. Is it better here to replace list with a concurrent container for example?

Comment: If you do not want your list data changed by other classes you schould return a copy and not the reference of original list.

Comment: @sgplait, mostly I return a `Stream<>()` - I'm using a `List<>` in the example as it's a little more universal... But the same question applies.. (AFAIK, streams - unless backed by a concurrent container are not thread-safe.!?!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe, because a thread can read the list while another thread modifies it.

1. Return a copy of the list (not efficient if there are many reads).
2. Use [copy-on-write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) list.
3. Store a new instance of the list in `modifyFoos`.

Comment: Either return a copy of the list (defensive-copy) or if it is thread-safe then you have no problems (also take care when iterating it, except it is a CopyOnWriteArrayList).

Comment: I was hoping for some *container magic sauce*, ah well, I'll stick to returning copies..

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "container magic sauce"? Also you should use some synchronization there.

Comment: Container magic can't help you when you are using the list out of the singleton. You may consider option 3 if writes are rare compared to reads (this is usually the case).

Comment: Structural changes to the list(or other containers) are indeed rare, the individual `Foo`s are properly synchronized - the question was more around whether it's *safe* to return the original list - unrealistic expectations on the conainer for my part...